# Python - Have function store list of arguments called over

Tags: python, function

I am looking for a standard way to have a function store a list of tuples or keyword dicts that contain an ordered sequence of the arguments it has been called on.

For example, if I define the function

```py
def f(x, y=None):
    return x, y
```

and then run

```
>>> f('foo')
>>> f(1, 0)
```

then the hypothetical attribue `f.call_history` would contain

```py
[('foo', None), (1, 0)]
```

or

```py
[{'x': 'foo', 'y': None}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}]
```

Does something like this already exist or if not what would be the best way to implement it?

Comment: you can create external list for values and inside `f()` append values to this list.

Comment: What's your end goal here? This seems like something that should be tracked *outside* of the function.

Comment: @wjandrea: That is currently how it is done. I was just trying to explore the space of other possible implementations in case there was a more elegant approach to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been possible to add attributes to function since [PEP 232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/). A decorator would be a nice way to handle this "outside" the function itself:

```
>>> def track_history(f):
...     hist = []
...     def wrapper(*a, **kw):
...         hist.append((a, kw))
...         return f(*a, **kw)
...     wrapper.call_history = hist
...     return wrapper
...
>>>
>>> @track_history
... def f(x, y=None):
...     return x, y
...
>>>
>>> print(f.call_history)
[]
>>>
>>> f('foo')
('foo', None)
>>> f(1, 0)
(1, 0)
>>>
>>> f.call_history
[(('foo',), {}), ((1, 0), {})]
```

Comment: Nice, yeah this is spot on! Although I am kinda surprised that something this doesn't already exist in the standard libraries. I would have thought it would be useful for logging and debugging, etc.

Comment: I think it'd be more common to use the `logging` module for, well, logging this kind of thing (and you could factor that out into a decorator too). There's a big downside to the approach demonstrated here: the `call_history` list is growing endlessly, so a function that's called frequently in a long-running process could gobble up quite a bit of memory.